# iOS Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_kUTTypeImage"

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller, linker-errors

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_kUTTypeImage", referenced from:
      -[ViewController receiveNotification:] in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm adding a UIImagePickerController to my app and when I go to compile I get the above error. I found a solution on SO:

[Symbol not found: kUTTypeImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144961/symbol-not-found-kuttypeimage)

> Look up the symbol (kUTTypeImage) and locate the image/library it should exist in (MobileCoreServices.framework in this case). Then link your binary with that framework.

Problem is, I'm not sure how to implement it. How do I look up the symbol and then link it to the framework?

Should of noted I already have the MobileCoreServices framework imported. Here's the relevant code:

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
                 UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

                UIImagePickerController* myCamera = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
                myCamera.delegate = self;
                myCamera.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
                myCamera.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *) kUTTypeImage, nil];
                myCamera.allowsEditing = NO;
                [self presentModalViewController:myCamera animated:YES];

            }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only need to add and then import the framework into your project (or rather, target). In the Navigator, click on your project, and select a target. Then go to the Build Phases tab and, if it's not expanded already, expand Link Binary With Libraries. Then add MobileCoreServices.framework. In the file you want to use kUTTypeImage, add this import:

`#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>`

Note that you use angle brackets (<>) and not quotes as you would normally.

Comment: Should of noted this, I already have the framework added and imported on my viewcontroller. See the edits above.

Comment: You followed both steps (first adding, then importing)? Then it should work without problems. Confirm that MobileCoreServices is in the Link Binary With Libraries list.

Comment: See screen capture added to the question (not the error badge). Did you see the link to the other SO post on this. Apparently there's an issue at times with this.

Comment: In the other SO post, the solution is exactly as I said. What I do notice, is that you've added the library to your unit test target (IntegrationSiteReportT...). In your scheme selector on the left, it appears that you're building your regular target. Did you add the framework to both targets? If you did, I have no idea why it doesn't work...

Comment: Oh for the love of God, yep, that's what I did. Huzzah for a fresh set of eyes. Thanks for the help. Drop an answer on here so I can credit you.

Comment: No worries, happens to the best. I've edited my answer to be more accurate (add the framework to the target instead of project), so you can accept this answer if you'd like.