# "Use of undeclared identifier" even though Framework linked and header file imported

Tags: ios, objective-c

I copy and pasted the following line of code into a .m file:

> uiipc.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *)kuTTypeImage];

But even though I had linked MobileCoreServices.framework and did `#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>` I can't get rid of this error:

> Use of undeclared identifier 'kuTTypeImage'

**Background**

I copied this piece of code from http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/system/files/lectures/Lecture%2017_0.pdf to add picture taking capabilities to my iPhone app.

From [Symbol not found: kUTTypeImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144961/symbol-not-found-kuttypeimage) I figured out I had to link MobileCoreServices.framework.  I indepedently figured out I had to `#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>`.  I think I've done everything by the book, but why am I still getting this error?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem stems from having copied and pasted the line of code before linking the framework and importing the correct header file.

I managed to fix the problem by re-writing the line of code.  When I began typing `kuTTypeImage` Xcode's code completion found the variable.  So I let code completion finish the variable name and the error suddenly dissapeared.

Comment: It's because you had a lowercase `u` in your identifier when the actual identifier has an uppercase `U`. In case you haven't already figured that out, that is.

Comment: @DrBeardface you're right! You totally rock.  Thank you.